# what is the different about subprocess.call in python between direct command line input?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have encountered a problem when I used python script to invoke a FEM software Abaqus. Here is it:
When I used the script to start a abaqus job the abaqus was call but an error occurred during pre-process within the software:

```
subprocess.call(["abaqus job=job_name oldjob=oldjob_name user=user.for int  scratch=C:\Temp"],shell=True)
```

But when I called "abaqus job=job_name oldjob=oldjob_name user=user.for int  scratch=C:\Temp" in command line directly, it worked.
Is there any difference between the two ways?

Comment: What specific error are you getting when you call it? Can you share the Traceback?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. It is my careless action that the job file is modified in the script without closing it, which makes the job file unavailable in the subprocess call. So the question is meaningless and I will close it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split up your argument list:

```
subprocess.call(["abaqus", "job=job_name", "oldjob=oldjob_name", "user=user.for", "int", "scratch=C:\Temp"], shell=True)
```

This tells `call` that these are individual arguments. If you pass one long string, it thinks that is a single argument.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't work either. In windows it works without splitting the argument list. It seems that the pre.exe within abaqus works different in the two ways above.

Comment: You actually shouldn't split up the argument list like this if you're using `shell=True`. The whole command should be inside a string.